# Regex to catch 14 digits number that starts with 25 within a text string

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have created a regex that catches only numbers that are 14 digits long and start with 25, which works correctly.

```
if (preg_match('/(?=\d{14}$)(25)\d+/', $valid_id)){
    $return_value = 1;
}
```

If I type something before the number it works fine. However, as soon as I write something (space, letter, digit) after the number the regex stops working and no longer catches it.

**For example:**

```
$valid_id = "the id is 25000000000000";
```

It catches the number, but if I write

```
$valid_id = "the id is 25000000000000 and it is valid";
```

Then it doesnt.

I presume I am missing something at the end of the regex, but cant figure it out.

Comment: Word boundaries are used to match whole words, `'/\b(?=\d{14}\b)25\d+/'`. You may  also write it as `'/\b25\d{12}\b/'`. And then consider other types of boundaries: `'/(?<!\S)25\d{12}(?!\S)/'`, `'/(?<!\d)25\d{12}(?!\d)/'`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.!

Comment: You are very welcome :)